# changing language in java

Tags: java, struts

i used .properties files to manage the language in java code.
but how to change the language manually, i mean when the user want to change the language.
in other word what google and facebook did to manage this ?

Comment: You should be a bit more specific, that question doesn't make sense.  Are you referring to human language selection for automatic translation, optional coding languages, or sub-sections per language on a website, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to set the Locale that matches your users selection. There are some issues that you need to be aware of, but it should be fairly straight forward.
There are a couple guides to get you started [here](http://www.webreference.com/programming/Globalize-Web-Applications12_Java/), and [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/locale/)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at storing your UI texts in [resource bundles](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29), then offer your users a choice of locales that are known to the application and reload the UI for the user from the bundle loaded using the locale chosen.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm  form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
            setLocale(request, Locale.ITALY);  // This is inherited method. 
            return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);

}
```

Call **setLocale()** method with arguments **request** and **java.util.Locale**.
Make sure that you have respective **ApplicationResource_it_IT.properties** in your resource path in this case.